# What are some good Stack Overflow-style discussion boards for general programming issues?

Tags: stack-overflow, discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I ask questions that aren't Stack Overflow questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-stack-overflow-questions)

What are some good Stack Overflow-style discussion boards for general programming issues?

It irks me that I've come across many interesting discussions on SO (some with hundreds of upvotes) that have been closed on the grounds of being unconstructive, (because the answer was a matter of opinion or couldn't be provided in a short enough response).

I'm looking for a site that's a less militant than SO in this regard and is a nice place to while away my lunchtimes.

Comment: The programmers page of SO is for opinion based questions relating to programming practices.

Comment: Take a look at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: To answer your question, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ may be more suitable to what you are looking for. Check the [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) there before asking, though.

Comment: @Oded - We don't do discussions on Programmers either

Comment: @ChrisF - True enough. Though programmers is more suitable for some "general programming issues".

Answer (score 6):

> What are some good StackOverflow style discussion boards for general programming issues?

Unfortunately there isn't such a place, Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange in general are Q&A sites, not discussion boards.

Some good alternatives that welcome open ended discussions are [Quora](http://www.quora.com/) and [Progit](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming).

Comment: So did the former answer here suggesting P.SE raise your blood pressure, or is it just par for the course at this point?

Comment: @Adam: I used it to try and get a rise out of him, but Anna stepped in before his blood pressure could get to dangerous levels.

Comment: @The - oh that was *your* answer?  I hadn't noticed the author first time.  In any event, if Yannis's MSO gravitar is any indication, perhaps Anna acted in everyone's best interest :)

Comment: @Adam: No, it wasn't my answer. I mean that I shared it with Mr. Yahoo to try to provoke a rise.